# How do I configure SSL on mongoDB server?

Tags: database, mongodb, ssl, server, nosql

I have setup my own mongoDB and enabled authorization that’s hosted on an external server.
Which i can now connect to my DB using mongo Compass while mongoDB is:
bindIp : 0.0.0.0
But not any other things else.

Then I found this thread on the mongoDB community forum:
[here](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/i-cant-set-bindip/4042)

Stating that there’s a misconception on bindIp. Which it does not listen to remote ip that wants to connect, but listen to only local network. In order to connect to my mongoDB with a remote ip while not opening all my port to public (0.0.0.0) i need to set up a SSL connection.

Now here’s the problem. How do i setup SSL connection ? I took the class M301 and know about X.509 but still have no clue how to connect via SSL.
I would like to connect through something like with the connection string of:
mongod://:@XXX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXXX/?ssl=true <<<<
If X.509 is the method, how do i work with pem key ? how do i sign one ? how do i use client key in mongo compass?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a certificate, MongoDB documentation provides guides for setting up TLS on the server. How to create the certificate is usually not covered; typically you would either work for a company whose IT department would take care of this for you, or you would use a service such as MongoDB Atlas which would handle TLS termination.

For learning purposes you can use self-signed certificates and there is probably a university course for setting up TLS.